# How to subset data using local macros

Tags: loops, for-loop, subset, stata, stata-macros

I have some code that uses local macros in Stata to subset an aggregate data set into quantiles by asset size. That code looks like this:

```
local quantile 0 25 50 75 99                
  foreach quantile in `quantile' {
      preserve                

  //Template for the top quantile in set
      if `quantile' == 99 {
          egen bottomcutoff = pctile(assets), p(`quantile')
          keep if assets > bottomcutoff
      }
      
  //Template for the bottom quantile in set
      else if `quantile' == 0 {
          local quantile10=`quantile'+10
          egen topcutoff = pctile(assets), p(`quantile10')
          keep if assets <= topcutoff
      }
      
  //Template for middle quantiles of distance 24
      else if `quantile' == 75 {
          egen bottomcutoff = pctile(assets), p(`quantile')
          local quantile10=`quantile'+24
          egen topcutoff = pctile(assets), p(`quantile10')
          keep if assets > bottomcutoff & assets <= topcutoff
      }
      
  //Template for middle quantiles of distance 25
      else {
          egen bottomcutoff = pctile(assets), p(`quantile')
          local quantile10=`quantile'+25
          egen topcutoff = pctile(assets), p(`quantile10')
          keep if assets > bottomcutoff & assets <= topcutoff
      }
          }
```

I'm trying to retrofit this code to subset by asset size thresholds instead of by percentile, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to get it to work properly with this local method. The thresholds I need are less than 10, between 10-100 (i just averaged to 55 because I don't know a better way to call it), and greater than 100. Here's what I've tried so far:

```
local subset 10 55 100
        foreach subset in `subsets' {
        preserve                

    //Template for the  subset greater than 100000000
        if `subset' == 100 {
            gen subset_obs = (assets >= 100000000)
            bysort company_id : egen subset_id = max(subset_obs)
            keep if subset_id == 1
        }
        
    //Template for less than or equal to 10000000
        else if `subset' == 10 {
            gen subset_obs = (assets <= 10000000)
            bysort company_id : egen subset_id = max(subset_obs)
            keep if subset_id == 1
        }
        
    //Template for between 10000000 and 100000000
        else if `subset' == 55 {
            gen subset_obs = (assets > 10000000 & assets < 100000000)
            bysort company_id : egen subset_id = max(subset_obs)
            keep if subset_id == 1
        }
        
        }
```

Comment: You need to describe your data better to explain what you are trying to do. For example, what is the unit of observation, i.e. what does each row represents. This line `bysort company_id : egen subset_id = max(subset_obs)` makes me believe that it is a panel dataset with company-time as unit of observation. If that is true, should all rows for a company kept in the subset if only one time period is within the threshold, or just the row within the threshold?

Comment: I agree with @TheIceBear: this isn't very clear. Why show the first block of code, which is about subsetting regardless of company and nothing to do with the second block of code?  Using `summarize, detail` or `centile` directly is a better way to proceed than by putting constant percentiles into variables with `egen`.

Comment: Cross-posted at https://www.reddit.com/r/stata/comments/qkk7l8/how_to_subset_data_using_local_macros_in_stata/  Telling people about cross-posting is always courteous, as you've been reminded before, Nate/Ignatios.

Comment: Quantiles are levels of the data. Using the term for the bins, classes or intervals they delimit is common but still awkward.

Comment: Hi everyone, thanks for trying to help. I should have provided more detail, it is a panel data set with company_id-time as the unit of observation. I will be sure to mention cross posting in the future.

The reason I am trying to get it to coalesce with the top portion of the code is because this code is a part of a larger script that I am trying to retrofit with system of locals it uses to subset the panel data into quantiles, but now I'm trying to get it to subset by asset-size threshold. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Sorry. but the comment does not explain to me why the earlier code is relevant or why  it makes any sense to relate the two blocks of code. In one problem you need to calculate quantiles from the data and company identifiers are ignored. In the other problem you know where the breaks should be in advance and company identifier is crucial. The only link between the problems is superficial in that you are identifying subsets, and not even the same number of subsets.  Any local macros are just arbitrary here.  You could loop over 10 55 100 or a b c or anything else convenient or inconvenient.

Comment: You haven't addressed the comment in my answer that your second code would identify subsets that overlap, unless exceptionally all companies stay within the same assets band.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a complete answer but it would be much harder to read as a comment.

Consider the results of

```
gen which = cond(assets <= 1e7, 1, cond(assets <= 1e8, 2, 3)) 

bysort company_id (which) : replace which = which[_N]
```

That's a simpler way of selecting whether something was ever true than using `egen, max()`. Note that using `1e7` and `1e8` releases the reader from counting zeros.

This code classifies companies by the highest assets band they ever reached: not higher than 10 million (unstated currency units), not higher than 100 million, or higher still.

A consequence of your code is that the classification is not guaranteed disjoint. In principle a company that straddles two or three bands would be selected for two or three subsets. Perhaps that is what you want.

This comment is optimistic and assumes that `assets` is never missing. If it is, then the code needs to be more careful, as missing counts as arbitrarily large and so larger than 1e8.